# Graphing the time of computing of a particular function in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, time

I am trying to graph the time needed for python to computer the factorial of integers between 1 and 150.

My script calculates the different time just fine and I am able to print them but when I try to graph it I am getting a value error, saying that my sequence is too large.

How can I solve this?

This is my code:

```
import numpy as np
import time
start_time = time.time()
n = np.linspace(1,151)
for i in range(151) : 
    np.math.factorial(i)
    dt = ((time.time()-start_time))
    plot(n,dt)
```

Comment: Can you post your plot function? My suspicion is that you need `n=np.linspace(1,152)`

Answer (score 0):

You need to collect your run times in a list `dt` to plot them:

```
import numpy as np
import timeit

from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

start_time = timeit.default_timer()

r = range(1, 151)
dt = []
for i in r: 
    np.math.factorial(i)
    dt.append(timeit.default_timer()-start_time)
plt.plot(r, dt)
```

Result:

[image]